# Ajax JSON response into HighCharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, highcharts

I'm trying to add dynamic data to my HighCharts graph which has came directly from an AJAX Request.

Here's the JSON response from my AJAX call :

```
{
    "Data1":[17342,2424742,96496,13516,3262472,472722,278452],
    "Data2":[1213263,139300,21361,3724247,2474274,248835,135155],
    "Data3":[4727,427485,357,5383,483853,247472,247277]
}
```

Here's the function in which I'll be passing the JSON response too:

```
function createGraph(response) {

        $('#container').highcharts({
                credits: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                chart: {
                    type: 'line'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Profit Graph'
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: 'Data from the past week'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'datetime',
                    dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                        day: '%b %e',
                            week: '%b %e'
                    }
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                            text: 'Price'
                    },
                    min: 0
                },
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function() {
                            return '<span style="color:#33333;">'+this.series.name +': '+ Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y,0);
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Data1',
                    data: /*show Data1 from AJAX Response*/,
                    pointStart: Date.UTC(2014, d.getUTCMonth(), weeks_ago(new Date())),
                    pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
                    color: '#55CCA2',
                }, {
                    name: 'Data2',
                    data: /*show Data2 from AJAX Response*/,
                    pointStart: Date.UTC(2014, d.getUTCMonth(), weeks_ago(new Date())),
                    pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
                    color: '#3498db',
                }, {
                    name: 'Data3',
                    data: /*show Data3 from AJAX Response*/,
                    pointStart: Date.UTC(2014, d.getUTCMonth(), weeks_ago(new Date())),
                    pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
                    color: '#0B79C3',
                }]
        });

};

$.get(window.AjaxURL, {'action': 'graphData'}, function(response) {
        createGraph(response);
});
```

How would I be able to parse this data into the specified series?

Comment: for series Data1, data will be Variable_Storing_Your_Ajax_Result.Data1...
for series Data2, data will be Variable_Storing_Your_Ajax_Result.Data2...for series Data3, data will be Variable_Storing_Your_Ajax_Result.Data3....... You may first need to jQuery.parseJSON(response);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create json Object :

```
var jsonObj=JSON.parse(response);
```

Now you can get Data1,Data2,Data3 data using `jsobjObj.Data1` , `jsonObj.Data2` and `jsonObj.Data3`.